# Xcode Color picker automatically changing HSB color

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, color-picker

I am having a strange issue using the integrated color picker of Xcode (version 6.3):

After I assign a color to a any item (in my case a UIButton) and then try to enter a new hue value, **just by clicking the textfield the color changes**. All three values (hue, saturation and brightness) change. Funny enough this change is visible as the color of the button changes, but the actual values stay the same until expecting a color in another view and then switching back to the button inspection, the value sliders do kind of thingy in between, they change a little bit, stay neither on the old nor the "new" value.

1. step: set the color (in "Levelselect"; "Play" is there for comparison)
   [image: the inital value]
   The correct h, s and b values are set.
2. step: click on one of the three values, in this case "hue"
   [image: after clicking a value]
   As you can see the color changes, the sliders change a tiny bit but the values stay the same.
3. step: inspect the color of another item or do some crazy clicking around to tell make xcode actually read the color again
   [image: the new values]
   Look at the new values and be confused what happened.

My questions now are:

- Is this a known issue?
- Is there a workaround?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Can anybody reproduce that issue or is it somehow related to my machine/setup?

Answer (score -1):

Next to "HSB Sliders" dropdown you can see a settings wheel. Tap in it and set "Generic RGB"