# UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha: produces different color than storyboard sliders

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicolor

I ran into issue with the storyboard where I tried to reproduce the color picked in the storyboard in code.
I made a little sample app to show you what I mean:
In the storyboard I made a simple viewcontroller with a button in the middle. I set up the background color of the view and the button as below:
[Color picker in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27nGq.png)

And I wired the button to this piece of code which produced the logs below:

```
- (IBAction)testColor:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;
    [sender.backgroundColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    NSLog(@"\nred:%f\ngreen:%f\nblue:%f\nalpha:%f\n", red, green, blue, alpha);

    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:223 / 255.0f green:175 / 255.0f blue:0 / 255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [sender.backgroundColor getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    NSLog(@"\nred:%f\ngreen:%f\nblue:%f\nalpha:%f\n", red, green, blue, alpha);
}

2015-11-24 18:20:43.812 colorTest[9311:205700]red:0.840786
green:0.629816
blue:0.030545
alpha:1.000000
2015-11-24 18:20:43.815 colorTest[9311:205700] 
red:0.874510
green:0.686275
blue:0.000000
alpha:1.000000
```

[Screen before (left) and after (right) clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnfUr.png)

Can someone explain what causes the difference between the storyboard and code values and how I can work around this so I can consistently use colors?

Comment: yeah, that happens for me as well. Xcode slider kind of work on some separate RGB scales. they are not the actual colors which you are hoping for.

Comment: haha, srsly? that "bug" still exists? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975262/xcode-color-picker-automatically-changing-hsb-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the color to "Generic RGB". Next to "RGB Sliders" dropdown (in Interface Builder) you may see a settings wheel. Tap in it and set "Generic RGB". This may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve it. It was giving me quite a headache.